# How to make a div draggable even from a textarea within?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a draggable div which can also be dragged from a textarea within it.

html:

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

css:

```
#divContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#divContainer").draggable();
```

I can drag the `div` if I drag by clicking in the `div` area, but not if I click into the `textarea` area.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Here is the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QW7B7/2/)

Comment: @Francois Wahl I don't want to make the textarea draggable. I want the DIV to be also dragged if i drag it by clickin in the textarea.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I thought. I don't know how though. Maybe you need to attach to the textarea drag/mousedown/etc.. event(s). Though I assume this would be rather tricky, seeing that `drag` in an textarea assumes you want to highlight the text inside it. You could achieve this with a transparent overlay but then you would loose the textarea's default features. You might be better off to create a border or frame the user needs to use to drag the div.

Comment: When a text area is clicked, the default action is to get focused. As Francois mentioned, you can use an overlay. So in that case, how the textarea will get focused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Out this fiddle perfect for you

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/victordas/cbnuL/)

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
 <textarea name="ta" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
 background-color:#aaa;
 padding: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 position:relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('div').draggable({
 cancel: "ta",
 start: function (){
    $('#ta').focus();
 } ,
 stop: function (){
    $('#ta').focus();
 } 
});
```

Comment: The only issue is though, how can we select text inside the texarea? I think any solution will sacrafice some default features from the elements. Also you need to have additional code to ensure you only focus on the element which started the drag, ensure no focus occurs on stop if drag was started by the div itself. You might need to differentiate between input elements as a checkbox or radio button might not want to have focus after drag. If possible when creating a draggable form-like container which has input elements a separate draggable element would be easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: While this answer may work for this specific situation, the reasoning is wrong. The `cancel` option does not work like that and the `id` attribute is entirely irrelevant. See the answer by Wahl for correct usage and the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) for the reason (the `cancel` option is a jQuery selector which defaults to `input,textarea,button,select,option`. Setting it to anything that does _not_ include `textarea` will allow dragging - the option set in this answer simply cancels dragging on `<ta></ta>` elements only - making it work)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [**cancel**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) option, setting it to `''`, similar to this:

```
$("#divContainer").draggable({ cancel: '' });
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QW7B7/12/) - Using the `cancel` option

---

Though this works for dragging, it causes other issues.

You are now unable to click into the textarea itself as `draggable` takes over the event.
You would have to write some custom code now to work around this.

Using an overlay is also a problem to implement as you now have to deal with when to place it over the div and when not.

I would recommend to leave the default functionality of any elements inside the draggable div as is instead of "hacking" around them.

---

#### Possible Alternative

---

A more user-friendly approach might be to add a frame-like border to the div or a header-like border at the top to enable to user to drag the div.

Using HTML similar to this:

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div class="dragger"></div>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

Giving the `dragger` the following css:

```
.dragger {
    border: none;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

and updating your `textarea` css to not use absolute positioning but instead use margins to specify the 5px on the left and top.

```
#text {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

You then can implement the [**handle**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) option similar to this:

```
$("#divContainer").draggable({
    handle: '.dragger'
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aDcL/) - Using a header to drag

---

I'm not sure if this is a solution you can use or not but it would be one option.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: I added an alternative, similar to how a draggable dialog would do it, using a designated area for dragging. Though I'm aware that you might be restricted and not be able to use it, any other solution most likely requires some hacky magic and will propably cause you issues when addressing bugs or enhancing the functionality. Though I'm not aware of it, I wouldn't be surprised if someone already wrote a plug-in  or similar for this which works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/udupog/1/)

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#move').css('top',$("#text").css('top'));

  $('#move').css('left', $("#text").css('left'));
  $("#divContainer").draggable();
  $("#move").draggable({drag:function(event,ui){
  $('#text').css('top',$("#move").css('top')); 
  $('#text').css('left', $("#move").css('left'));
  },grid:[1,1],stop:function(){
  $('#move').css('top',$("#text").css('top'));

  $('#move').css('left', $("#text").css('left'));

  }});

});
```